# Automate move new files after a set period of time

Tags: filesystem, automation

I receive files though a service at odd intervals and need to have them available in one folder for 72 hours before being archived in a different folder.  I would like to automate this process.  Ideally this would be a service that watches the "in-use" folder for new files, notes the time of their arrival, then moves them to the archive 3 days later.

I am currently running a crontab entry that runs every 72 hours to move the entire contents of the in-use folder to the archive folder.  This causes a sync issue between the availability window for a given file and it moving when it is no longer needed.

Comment: This looks appropriate for a [Systemd path](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html) job.

Comment: New files come in to Folder A at random from outside the server.  They need to sit in Folder A for 72 hours, then move to Folder B where they live forever.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this will work:

```
find /source/location -maxdepth 1 -mtime +3 -type f -exec mv "{}" /destination/location/ \;
```

How this works:

- `find` will look for items in `/source/location`
- `-maxdepth 1` will limit the search to just the directory specified, ignoring subdirectories
- `-mtime +3` will limit results to 3 days *or older*
- `-type f` will limit results to files only
- `-exec` will run a command on those results, in this case it’s `mv`
- `"{}"` is where the result of `find` will go
- `\;` tells `find` that the command passed for `exec` is complete

Throw this in your cron job and have it run hourly if you wish. Only files that are 72 hours or older will be moved

Comment: Nice and simple! I learned here that the quotes around the placeholder actually are never needed - names with spaces are also correctly handled without them.

Comment: Wow!!  Asked and answered.  Thank you so much!