# how to us the chown command and mv with find command

Tags: command-line, permissions, find, chown, plex

I have been searching around and found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369521/automate-move-new-files-after-a-set-period-of-time) question which almost solved my problem. The goal is to have a folder on Ubuntu server which other computers connect to and save files. I have two directories ('Movies' and 'TV') inside a folder called 'import'. I modified the command to work perfectly to transfer those files to my actual Plex media directory. The only thing I can't figure out is how to change the ownership of the files to the plex user. Is there a way to use the `chown` command before moving the files?

I don't want to mess with the import directory because someone (nobody:nogroup) could be writing to it when the `chown` command executes. The alternative is to apply the `chown -R plex:plex` command on my `/mnt/nfs-plex`, but then I am doing that over and over again on my files causing unnecessary hard drive activity. I included my modified version of the commands.

Movies:

```
find /mnt/import/Movies/ -maxdepth 1 -mmin +30 -type f -exec mv "{}" mnt/nfs-plex/Movies \;
```

TV:

```
find /mnt/import/TV/* -maxdepth 0 -mmin +30 -type d -exec mv "{}" /mnt/nfs-plex/TV \;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you can either nest two `-exec` actions after each other like so:

```
find ... -exec chown ... {} \; -exec mv {} ... \;
```

Or use a bash command string like so:

```
find ... -exec bash -c 'chown ... "$1" && mv "$1" ...' _ {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks! The first command worked. I only know very basic commands in Linux. I need to find somewhere to learn the command line.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=bash+scripting+bible+pdf&ia=software